# Does SSO allow seamless use without account creation?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

During our pilot of the free version of Stack Overflow for Teams we are getting push back from users due to account fatigue. They do not want to create Stack Overflow account to access the company knowledge base.

I understand that Single Sign On (SSO) is a feature of the paid tiers; and I want to learn more how it works. Does it allow for a new user to go straight into asking/answering questions, or does it still require them to create an account?

How does billing work in conjunction with Single Sign On? Is every person in our organization considered a paid user, even if they never use Stack Overflow for Teams?
We are on Azure Active Directory (AD) if that makes any difference.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/5004535-single-sign-on-sso-overview, with Azure AD setup described [here](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4538476-configure-single-sign-on-with-azure-ad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to Stack Overflow for Teams requires a Stackoverflow.com account even with Single Sign-On. That said, the disruptions are minimal. Once they've initially logged into Stack Overflow they will not need to log in again unless they manually log out, and how often they need to re-authenticate with your identity provider is configurable.

Enabling Single Sign-On **will not** automatically bill you for every user in your organization. We only bill against active accounts on your Team. That means we will only bill you for users that have logged into your Team. Please note that we define an active user as any user that has logged into your Team and currently has access, it is not based on their usage of your Team.